# How can a kid fly with one parent and return with the other?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, one-way

I have a plan to fly with my kid to my parents (CDG-FRA) for the sake of example), leave the kid there for a couple of weeks and then let my wife do the same flight and bring the kid back.

If I were to be on both flights, that wouldn't be a problem: I could book a round trip for myself and the kid for the whole duration of the holyday (CDG to FRA on day D and return on day D+14), and then just book a round trip for myself in the opposite direction (FRA to CDG on D+1 and return on D+13). However, I will be busy on D+13, so I wonder if my wife could fly instead, without booking super-expensive one-way tickets for every flight.

What options do I have?

EDIT: the airline in question is Lufthansa, and my kid is 5 y.o. (so he needs a child ticket).

Comment: Have you actually priced the one-way tickets?  Many airlines don't charge extra for one-way tickets anymore, especially on "domestic" flights like intra-Schengen.  Two one-ways might be the same price as a round-trip.

Comment: By the way, if CDG-FRA is the real itinerary, I suppose you've checked rail as another option?  It seems to be competitive in both time and price, and avoids the whole one-way issue.

Comment: @NateEldredge No, CDG-FRA is not the real itinerary. And yes, I have checked one-way tickets and they are about as expensive as round-trip ones.

Comment: Not an answer, but might be relevant: Are you aware that kids can fly alone? Lufthansa offers this for kids up the age of 5, so you might want to take this service instead. See http://www.lufthansa.com/de/de/Alleinreisende-Kinder for details. It most certainly is cheaper (within Europe 60€) than a separate return ticket and if you you are ok with this service and think your kid will be ok it is a great time saver.

Comment: @dirkk Thanks for this! This is indeed relevant to my case.

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing that a reservations agent at Lufthansa might be able to arrange, even if the website doesn't allow it.  I'd recommend calling their reservations line and seeing whether they can help you.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible using only return tickets, buy yourself a return ticket from CDG to FRA, leaving on D and returning on D+1. Then buy a return ticket for your wife, leaving on D+13 and returning on D+14. Your child can then have a ticket leaving on D and returning on D+14. With you/your wife being on a different booking it is unlike you will be seated together, you could try and ask if someone would be willing to swap or pay to choose your seats.

Comment: So far no online booking site I've seen offers to book a ticket for a kid alone without an adult sharing the exact same itinerary.

Comment: I think it would depend on how old the child is and the airline in question. I remember doing a similar thing with my parents a few years ago on Aurigny who's website allows you to book a lone child over the age of 15. You could also look at phoning the airline, they may be able to be more flexible and arrange this.

Comment: This must be a fairly regular occurance. I am sure airlines know how to deal with it.

Comment: @skifans Sorry for being unclear, my kid is 5. If he was 12 or older there wouldn't be a problem, since he would be considered adult as far as fare classes are concerned.

Comment: I swear I commented yesterday not to rely on people willing to swap! This is such entitled behaviour that really only parents could think of :( If you want a certain service *pay for it* and do not presume that just because you have a child suddenly the world will bend for you.

Comment: Ok, yeah it's probably unlikely that you could do that online. I'd recommend phoning Lufthansa.